# How to add customized symbols between nodes without affecting the graph?

Tags: function-construction, graphs-and-networks

Is it possible to add some customized symbols between nodes (just for presentation) without affecting the graph?

 This is an example where I added symbols of resistor, capacitor, and inductor between nodes. 
However, the condition is that they're just like fake symbols and not affecting the graph at all.
So the two graphs still have the same vertex list and edge  list:

```
EdgeList[g]   = EdgeList[g1]
VertexList[g] = VertexList[g1]
```

[image]

```
ellipseLayout[n_, {a_, b_}] := 
 Table[{a Cos[2 Pi/n u], -b Sin[2 Pi/n u]}, {u, 1, n}]; 
myGraphPlot[graph_] := 
 Graph[graph, VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Above], 
  VertexLabelStyle -> Red, 
  VertexStyle -> Directive[Red, EdgeForm@None], EdgeStyle -> Black, 
  VertexCoordinates -> 
   ellipseLayout[Length@(VertexList[graph]), {2, 1}]];
edges = {1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 4, 5 <-> 6};
g = myGraphPlot[edges]
```

Comment: I'd suggest you look into EdgeShapeFunction (an option for Graph).

Comment: @lericr Unfortunately it's only possible if there is an edge between two nodes. In my case, there is no edge between these two nodes.

Comment: Maybe Graph isn't the right construct for you. If you're just wanting to draw things between known points, then maybe just use graphics primitives. But if you want to stick with Graph, then just create a sort of "dual" graph that has the edges you need. You can merge the two graphs for presentation but can otherwise keep them separate and unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set Prolog with graphic primitives:

Define symbols:

```
resistor[{a1_, a2_}] :=
 Block[{d, l, res, s, t},
  d = a2 - a1;
  l = Norm[d];
  s = a1 (1 - 2/5) + a2 2/5;
  t = a1 (1 - 3/5) + a2 3/5;
  res = Line[
    Table[{Norm[t - s] i /16, 1/(6 l) Sin[i Pi/2]}, {i, 0, 16}]];
  res = GeometricTransformation[res, 
    Composition[TranslationTransform[s], 
     RotationTransform[ArcTan @@ d]]];
  {Thick, Darker[Green], Line[{{a1, s}, {t, a2}}], res}
  ]

capacitor[{a1_, a2_}] :=
 Block[{d, l, nd, res, s, t},
  d = a2 - a1;
  l = Norm[d];
  s = a1 (1 - 4.5/9) + a2 4.5/9;
  t = a1 (1 - 5/9) + a2 5/9;
  nd = l/15 RotationTransform[Pi/2][Normalize[d]];
  res = Line[{{s + nd, s - nd}, {t + nd, t - nd}}];
  {Thick, Darker[Green], Line[{{a1, s}, {t, a2}}], Brown, res}
  ]

inductor[{a1_, a2_}] :=
 Block[{d, l, res, s, t, r},
  d = a2 - a1;
  l = Norm[d];
  s = a1 (1 - 1/5) + a2 1/5;
  t = a1 (1 - 4/5) + a2 4/5;
  r = (Norm[s - t]/4 ) 1/2;
  res = Table[Circle[{i + r, 0}, r, {0, Pi}], {i, 0, 6 r, 2 r }];
  res = GeometricTransformation[res, 
    Composition[TranslationTransform[s], 
     RotationTransform[ArcTan @@ d]]];
  {Thick, Darker[Green], Line[{{a1, s}, {t, a2}}], {Black, res}}
  ]

dc[{a1_, a2_}] := Block[{d, l, res, s, t, r}, d = a2 - a1;
  l = Norm[d];
  s = a1 (1 - 2/5) + a2 2/5;
  t = a1 (1 - 3/5) + a2 3/5;
  r = Norm[s - t]/2;
  res = {Circle[{r, 0}, r], Line[{{2 r/4, r/4 }, {2 r/4, -r/4}}], 
    Line[{{{r/3 + r, r/4 }, {r/3 + r, -r/4}}, {{r/3 + r - r/4, 
        0 }, {r/3 + r + r/4, 0}}}]};
  res = GeometricTransformation[res, 
    Composition[TranslationTransform[s], 
     RotationTransform[ArcTan @@ d]]];
  {Thick, Darker[Green], Line[{{a1, s}, {t, a2}}], res}]
```

Set a new graph with Prolog:

```
coords = GraphEmbedding[g];
g1 = Graph[g, 
  Prolog -> {resistor[coords[[{4, 5}]]], capacitor[coords[[{2, 3}]]], 
    inductor[coords[[{1, 6}]]]}]
```

[image]

```
EdgeList[g] == EdgeList[g1]
```

> True

Comment: Actually coloring is not required but very nice code.

Comment: Not asked in the question, do you have a code for a DC voltage source, that would be nice as well. Something like this. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Voltage_Source.svg

Comment: And switch symbol like this. I found a post before drawing these symbols but stuck at modifying them to support coordinate as you did. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SPST_switch_symbol.svg

Comment: @hana I don't have the code.. but I just make one for dc..

Comment: @hana switch symbol could be done by modifying inductor code..

Comment: I tried modify the inductor for the switch. `res = Table[Circle[{i + r, 0}, r, {0, 2 Pi}], {i, 0, 6 r, 6 r}]` and how would you add the line of switch? I tried `res = Join[Table[Circle[{i + r, 0}, r, {0, 2 Pi}], {i, 0, 6 r, 6 r}], {Line[{0,0}, {-r, 3r}]` but got some error.

Comment: @hana you miss {} inside Line: Line[{{0,0}, {-r, 3r}}]

Comment: Thanks, it works now!!

Comment: What would be the logic to plot these symbols? I tried to check parameters step by step and see it works but still don't know how it works.