# Why does Mathematica return `$Failed` with this function definition?

Tags: functions, warning-messages

Why does Mathematica return `$Failed` with this function definition? 
 This function is from an answer in my [previous post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275217/how-to-add-customized-symbols-between-nodes-without-affecting-the-graph?noredirect=1#comment687246_275217) and it was working well. 
 I'm using Mathematica 13 on Windows 64 bit.

```
 capacitor[{a1_, a2_}] := Block[{d, l, nd, res, s, t}, d = a2 - a1;
      l = Norm[d];
      s = a1 (1 - 4.5/9) + a2 4.5/9;
      t = a1 (1 - 5/9) + a2 5/9;
      nd = l/15 RotationTransform[Pi/2][Normalize[d]];
      res = Line[{{s + nd, s - nd}, {t + nd, t - nd}}];
      {Thick, Darker[Green], Line[{{a1, s}, {t, a2}}], Brown, res}]
```

Answer (score 1):

It does work for me as expected - I'm using Wolfram Desktop 13.1 on macOS:

[image]

Comment: I was thinking it's my problem but afraid to restart Mathematica as I'll have to restart many programs.

Comment: What specific code produces `$Failed`? Just the definition above, or an attempt to use it? Can you post the code you are trying to run if it's the latter?

Comment: The definition alone returns failed.

Comment: I tried Remove[capacitor] and then excute the function definition again and it works!

Comment: @hana this is a good illustration of why it is good practice to `ClearAll` your function names before you define them. In this case, you would write something like `ClearAll[capacitor];` in the line before your definition of `capacitor`.

Comment: I see. I should make it a habit.